# Is it possible to reduce internal window reflection?

Tags: windows, glass

At night, my windows reflect the room and obscure the outside view. Is there a way to reduce the reflectiveness of the windows?

Comment: Window tinting. There are a few products that do this. Reduce glare is what you need.

Comment: Move the lights so they don't reflect where you're sitting.

Comment: A curtain or shade will do the trick.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are things such as anti-reflective/anti-glare film that many storefronts, counter displays use to increase see through. It's not often used privately though.

One example is this: https://www.ssidisplays.com/anti-glare-film-window-displays/

I'd try asking somewhere they sell glass for windows-panes or whole windows.

Just remember, it's very limited how much it would work with a lighted room, at night, looking out into the dark. Try lowering the light intensity in the room a bit as well, possibly. That could be done with a bulb of lower wattage.